# PowerShell command doesn't work when called from VBA, but otherwise works

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, xlwings

Currently I can't use xlwings because I can't access Windows' cmd. But I can access PowerShell, so I tried to change xlwings specific VBA code that calls the cmd to call the PowerShell instead.

When calling PowerShell with commands from VBA, it does not work. If I paste the exact same commands in the PowerShell terminal, it works as expected.

I've tried to compare the (not working) command VBA passes to PowerShell with the (working) command I manually paste into PowerShells terminal. But they look exactly the same.

The original xlwings code that calls the cmd

```vb
RunCommand = PythonInterpreter & " -B -c ""import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'" & PYTHONPATH & "')).split(';'); " & PythonCommand & """ "

ExitCode = Wsh.Run("cmd.exe /C " & _
           DriveCommand & RunCommand & _
           """" & WORKBOOK_FULLNAME & """ ""from_xl""" & " " & _
           Chr(34) & Application.Path & "\" & Application.Name & Chr(34) & " " & _
           Chr(34) & Application.Hwnd & Chr(34) & _
           " 2> """ & LOG_FILE & """ ", _
           WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn)
```

And my slightly modified version

```vb
RunCommand = "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe -B -c ""import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'" & PYTHONPATH & "')).split(';'); " & PythonCommand & """ "

ExitCode = Wsh.Run("Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit " & _
           DriveCommand & RunCommand & _
           """" & WORKBOOK_FULLNAME & """ ""from_xl""" & " " & _
           Chr(34) & Application.Path & "\" & Application.Name & Chr(34) & " " & _
           Chr(34) & Application.Hwnd & Chr(34) & _
           " 2> """ & LOG_FILE & """ ", _
           WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn)
```

The resulting command from aboves code. Working when pasted into PowerShells terminal directly, not working when executed from VBA:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe -B -c "import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'C:\Users\<placeholder>\test1;')).split(';'); import test1;test1.hello_xlwings()" "C:\Users\<placeholder>\test1\test1.xlsm" "from_xl" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\Microsoft Excel" "788640" 2> "C:\Users\<placeholder>\AppData\Roaming\xlwings.log"
```

I expect a simple "Hello, World!" in a specific Excel cell when clicking a button associated with the vba macro. Instead I get this error:

```
At line:1 char:213
+ ... X0RNZ\test1;')).split(';'); import test1;test1.hello_xlwings() C:\Use ...
+                                                                  ~
An expression was expected after "(".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

If I paste the command in the PowerShell terminal directly I get my expected result, "Hello, World!" shows up in my specific Excel cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `-Command` parameter. Depending on what `DriveCommand` contains, you should add `-Command` before `DriveCommand` or `RunCommand`.

Make sure there is a semicolon between de PowerShell commands and specify the command as a scriptblock, example:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command { cd "c:\folder";c:\folder\run.exe "param1" "param2" }
```

Run `powershell /?` for more examples.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the `-Command` parameter doesn't work, still the same error. Tried to put it before DriveCommand and before RunCommand, nothing worked. Since you asked what they contain: `DriveCommand = cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\"` and `RunCommand = "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe -B -c "import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'C:\Users\<placeholder>\test1;')).split(';'); import test1;test1.hello_xlwings()"`

Comment: A semicolon is needed to split the commands and the command should be enclosed in curly brackets or quotes, see updated answer

Comment: Tried to implement it this way but it still does not work, same error. My command is: `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command { cd C:\folder\Anaconda3;C:\folder\pythonw.exe -B -c "import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'C:\folder\test1;')).split(';'); import test1;test1.hello_xlwings()" "C:\folder\test1.xlsm" "from_xl" "C:\folder\Microsoft Excel" "788640" 2> "C:\folder\xlwings.log" }`. My workaround is a seperate `file.ps1` which I call with `-File` and passing the parameters. But I'd prefer to stick as close to the original code as possible.